# Match part of a regular expression back reference

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that will match a pattern that repeats at least twice, followed by part of the same pattern.

For example, abcabca should match, as should abcabcab, defdefdefde,  etcetera.

I think I need to use back references for this. I envision something like `^(.+?){2,}\1$` but somehow matching only part of the `\1` back reference.

Given the repeating pattern `abc`, I want to match at least 2 occurrences of `abc`, followed by part of the string `abc`.

These should match:

- `FooFooF`    (This is 2 repeats of `Foo` followed by the first letter in `Foo`)
- `FooFooFoo`  (This is either 3 repeats of Foo, followed by a 0-length substring or 2 followed by the entire word as a substring. It depends on how you look at it.)
- `FooFooFooFo` (This is 3 repeats followed by `Fo`, the first two letters in `Foo`)

These shouldn't:

- `Foo`   (There need to be 2+ repeats)
- `FooFo` (This is only 1 repeat)
- `FooFooFoX` (`FoX` is not part of the string `Foo`, so it doesn't match.)

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fit a pattern for 3 character you can use a regex like this:

```
\b(.{3})\1.*?\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pG2rY2/1)**

[image]

But if you want to have whatever pattern defined for the first characters then you could use:

```
\b(.+)\1.*?\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pG2rY2/2)**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this incorrectly matches patterns with an incorrect trailing part. For example, `abcabcabcd` matches. The trailing end needs to be part of the repeating pattern.

Comment: @xyzzy in your question you asked to repeat the pattern at least twice, so the string you mentioned is valid since abcabcabcd repeats abc tree times. If you want the pattern to be repeated without any character different than it you only have to use `\b(.+)\1+\b`

Comment: I guess I wasn't being clear with what I needed. I edited my question and added a better explanation and some examples.

Comment: @xyzzy you can use regex to get this this: FooFooFoo by using `\b(.+)\1*\b` but can't get `FooFooFooF` with a regex

Comment: Ah, it isn't possible then. Darn.